# undefined method `create_enum' error while migrating in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

So I'm working on an existing app and for some reason I was able to get it working and mirrored on my local environment however when I try migrating on heroku I get the below error, any ideas?

**Error:**

```
 (called from block in <top (required)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:23)
== 20141119113015 CreateReleasedInventoryStatus: migrating ====================
-- create_enum("eh_released_inventory_status", ["rejected", "pending", "allocated", "released", "transferred"])
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `create_enum' for #<CreateReleasedInventoryStatus:0x007fdc5d854c38>/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:661:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20141119113015_create_released_inventory_status.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transact
```

**Migration file:**

```
class CreateReleasedInventoryStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_enum("eh_released_inventory_status", ["rejected", "pending", "allocated", "released", "transferred"])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `power_enum` and it declared in `development` group of your `Gemfile`. So, Rails don't load it in `production` environment and it cause this error.

So, check your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting the following error: StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/power_enum-2.8.0/lib/power_enum/schema/schema_statements.rb:84:in `[]'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/power_enum-2.8.0/lib/power_enum/schema/schema_statements.rb:84:in `create_enum'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'

Comment: This is other problem. Try to create new SO post about it.

Comment: Ok created, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109395/no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-integer-when-migrating-in-production , cheers!