# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when migrating in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

So I'm working on an existing app and for some reason I was able to get it working and mirrored on my local environment however when I try migrating on heroku I get the below error, any ideas?

**Error:**

```
== 20141119113015 CreateReleasedInventoryStatus: migrating ====================
-- create_enum("eh_released_inventory_status", ["rejected", "pending", "allocated", "released", "transferred"])
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/power_enum-2.8.0/lib/power_enum/schema/schema_statements.rb:84:in `[]'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/power_enum-2.8.0/lib/power_enum/schema/schema_statements.rb:84:in `create_enum'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20141119113015_create_released_inventory_status.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
```

**Migration file:**

```
class CreateReleasedInventoryStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_enum("eh_released_inventory_status", ["rejected", "pending", "allocated", "released", "transferred"])
  end
end
```

**I'm also using the following gem:**

```
gem 'power_enum'
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the method signature and docs? [Here is the source](https://github.com/albertosaurus/power_enum/blob/master/lib/power_enum/schema/schema_statements.rb). It is looking for `table_name` and then a `Hash` not an `Array` this is your issue. The source is calling `[]` with a symbol to pull out options but you passed an `Array` where `[]` wants an `Integer`.

Comment: def change
    create_enum("eh_released_inventory_status" => ["rejected", "pending", "allocated", "released", "transferred"])
  end

Comment: this is not a column it is creating it is a table. These are not listed options that are passed in either e.g.`create_enum :released_inventory, :name_column => :status` will actually create a table called `released_inventories` with a column called `status`.

Comment: Thanks engineermnsky! which is why I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to convert this into a hash. Please advise! Cheers!!

Comment: I think I found a solution to your issue but I have not tested it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration syntax seems to be incorrect for the `power_enum` gem that you're using.

The gem's [README](https://github.com/albertosaurus/power_enum_2) says the syntax uses a name, then an options hash, such as:

```
create_enum("status", {…})
```

Whereas you're using a name, then an array:

```
create_enum("eh_released_inventory_status", […])
```

As far as I can tell, the solution is to change your migration line from what you posted to the `power_enum` syntax. The README has a bunch of examples, and also looks like it's thorough and very well documented.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense! Can you please provide an example, because I want to keep similar functionality via a Hash. Then I will accept your answer.

Comment: I've given you a +1 because what you said is right in theory, however, in this case because it's an existing app I'd rather make it work as is, without changing it.. There must be a way to have it work the way it is, because it works this way fine in Development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I've tested your code in a clean development environment, and the code has the same syntax error there too. Perhaps your development environment is using a different DB, or gem version, or is caching, or not reloading the tables, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you migration should look like this

```
class CreateReleasedInventoryStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_enum :released_inventory_status, name_column: :status, description: true, name_limit: 5
    ["rejected", "pending", "allocated", "released", "transferred"].each do |status| 
      ReleasedInventoryStatus.update_enumerations_model do |klass|
         #0.8.1 < version < 0.9.3 does not yield the klass 
         #in this case use: 
         #ReleasedInventoryStatus.create
         #in place of klass.create
         klass.create :name        => status,
                      :description => status.capitalize
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will create the table `released_inventory_statuses` with `status` and `description` columns with a limit of 5 unique statuses. Then it will populate `status` and `description` for each item in you list through `update_enumeration_model`. This should work for your use case but I have not tested this theory. My answer is purely based on how `create_enum` works and then this section of the README

> update_enumerations_model (since version 0.8.1)
>
> The preferred mechanism to update an enumerations model in migrations and similar. Pass in a block to this method to to perform any updates.